# Prove Harmonic Series Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, harmonic-numbers

Show that for all n ≥ 0: H2n ≤ 1 + n

I have already done it for bigger or equal to one to prove that it eventually reaches infinity but how would I do this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality holds for $n \ge 1$ ($H_0$ is not defined). Indeed, for $n \ge 1$,

\begin{align}
H_{2^n} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n}\\
&< 1 + \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\right) + \cdots + \Bigl(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}}_{2^{n-1}\, \text{times}}\Bigr)\\
&= 1 + \underbrace{1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{\text{$n-1$ times}}\\
&< 1 + n
\end{align}

Comment: well its 2^n, would that change your answer?

Comment: @no_sleep you mean $H_{2^n}$?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't it be different then? Your answer I mean.

Comment: @no_sleep yes it's different. I made some changes.

Comment: Thank you, its somewhat similar to my proof for 1+n/2.